# BlackBerry App build (PhoneGap)

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

I have created the project from node.js(Command prompt) by selecting platform as a blackberry.I have get the file structure from Node.js.So How can I import that project to build blackberry app.Which IDE should I used?

Please Help me out